# Unable to pass Program Files Path variable as the argument for the process

Tags: c#, .net

I want to return a directory inside a program files directory as a argument. I am getting that argument using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory . How do I properly format it to send it as argument.

Here is what I am doing now

```
String[] arguments = { Settings.Default.installDir, Settings.Default.executableName, "\"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\"" };
```

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns a directory residing in the program files (x86).

```
myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", arguments);
```

When I run it I get "PROGRAM_FILES GSSDesktopAlerts.exe \"C:\Program Files (x86)\somedir\somesubdir\\""

While launching I get System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: You'd better check StartInfo.Filename first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about using "\"".
You should use verbatim string. Ex: @"\".
Use Path.Combine instead "+" operator.